# NSURL convert mistake in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have some problem.. I want to take Text from URL with Swift but it has a problem in my code. Please can you check it ?

Here is my code;

```
@IBAction func getText() {
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://atakaractakip.co.nf/atakdeneme.txt")!
    var content: String; (contentsOfURL: NSURL (string: url)! , encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)  **/// The problem is here.. (Cannot convert value of type "NSURL" to expected argument type "String"**

    self.myLabel?.text = content
}
```

Comment: `url` is a `NSURL` object. So when you do `NSURL (string: something)`, `something` is a string! You should do `contentsOfURL:url` (since it's already a `NSURL`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the content present in your URL after we hit your URL in browser, we can do the following

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://atakaractakip.co.nf/atakdeneme.txt")!
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
    if data != nil {
        if let content = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {

        //It will display Onay AKPINAR as this is the content in your URL
        self.myLabel?.text = content
        }
    }
```

Or if you just want to display your url as text you can use

```
//It will display your url in label i.e. http://atakaractakip.co.nf/atakdeneme.txt
self.myLabel?.text = url.absoluteURL
```

Comment: Thank u so much i did it !!

Comment: @ÖnayAkpinar If it works for you, please accept as a tick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you have a url you can take its absoluteString. In your code it would be

```
@IBAction func getText() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://atakaractakip.co.nf/atakdeneme.txt")!
    var content = url.absoluteString
    self.myLabel?.text = content
}
```

and also you do not need to write `: NSURL` because the compiler will already know it by the initialisation `NSURL(string: "http://atakaractakip.co.nf/atakdeneme.txt")!`

Comment: I did this but program says,

var content must be let content when i fix it i didnt take the text from url i just see the url adress on my screen

Answer (score 0):

I would have used this way

```
@IBAction func getText() {

    let urlstring = "http://atakaractakip.co.nf/atakdeneme.txt"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlstring)

    self.myLabel?.text = urlstring
}
```